# Streaming to a variable instead of a file when using the requests library in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Python's **requests** package to download data from a remote server. Previously I was just downloading the whole response in one go like this:

```
response = requests.get(url=endpoint,
                        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                                 'Content-type': 'application/json'}
                        )
```

and then accessing the data by using the *response.json()* method:

```
reports = response.json()['data']['report']
```

however since some of the requests send back quite a lot of data that takes up to several minutes to download, I've been asked to implement a progress bar for each request so the user can monitor what's going on. The key here seems to be using the *stream=True* option when sending the GET request:

```
response = requests.get(url=endpoint,
                        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                                 'Content-type': 'application/json'},
                        stream=True)
```

then downloading the data in chunks like this:

```
with open('output_file', 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
        f.write(chunk)
        # print download progress based on chunk size and response.headers.get('content-length')
```

The bit where I'm stuck is that all the examples I've found using *response.iter_content()* write each chunk directly to a file when downloaded (as in the example above). Really I need to download the JSON data to a local variable so that I can do some manipulation/filtering of it **before** writing to disk, but I'm unsure how to achieve this when downloading the response in chunks.

Can anyone suggest how it could be done? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try: 1) downloading the file to the local file system first 2) reading file and doing required manipulation 3) saving file to disk again? I understand that somewhat a clumsy solution, but should work

Comment: That's basically my backup plan... but I'm just looking for a more elegant solution that doesn't involve temp files.

Comment: You can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile, that will at least save you the disk I/O.

Comment: @Ben I see. Just in case -  if the target OS is Linux, file maybe just something in RAM, not necessarily a HDD or SSD, so it maybe efficient enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`response.iter_content` gives you chunks. You can do whatever you want with them. You don't have to write them to a file.

For example, you could stick them in a list, and put them together and parse the result at the end:

```
import json

chunks = []
for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
    chunks.append(chunk)
    do_progress_bar_stuff()

full_content = b''.join(chunks)
parsed_data = json.loads(full_content)
do_stuff_with(parsed_data)
```

(I've avoided concatenating the chunks with `+` because that would cause quadratic runtime.)

Comment: That works brilliantly, thankyou. It seems obvious looking at it now...

I modified your line

    parsed_data = json.loads(full_content)

with

    reports = json.loads(full_content)['data']['report']

and I get back exactly the data structure I had using the old way.